# Looking for middleware from mongodb to tableau

Tags: mongodb, ssis, tableau-api

At the moment I’m trying to get mongodb to go to tableau via SSIS with Microsoft SQL server 2012 the main problem is that mongodb of course is a document orientated database and Microsoft SQL has issues with this because it’s a relational data base type program.

Is there any program that i can use as middle ware for tableau to read from, that will convert document oriented data bases into a relational data type that tableau will understand?

Answer (score 4):

Apache Drill might be useful to you. It provides an out of the box way to explore data in multiple formats, including Parquet, JSON, Hive. Basically, a big data ODBC connector that discovers schemas on the fly if there isn’t one already available. So you can get right down to exploring analyzing data without doing a major ingestion project, even if your data has some nested structure. Works on clusters or standalone.

Here’s a short video intro, and another showing using it with Tableau.
http://drill.apache.org/overview/

10 minute start example.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DRILL/Apache+Drill+in+10+Minutes#ApacheDrillin10Minutes-StartDrill

Tableau also has a Data Extract API that allows you to create extracts (static snapshots) from any external data source you like. The API is available for Java, C/C++, C# and Python. See http://www.tableausoftware.com/data-extract-api or search the Tableau knowledge base under support on their site.

Answer (score 3):

Having a browse of the Tableau community forums turned up a couple of things that may be of interest.

1. [Simba's MongoDB ODBC Driver with SQL Connector](http://www.simba.com/MongoDB-ODBC-Driver-SQL-Connector.htm)
2. [A community idea page for MongoDB support](http://community.tableausoftware.com/ideas/1426)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solid ODBC driver that also helps maintain the fidelity of your mongoDB data by exposing the nested MongoDB data model as a set of relational tables to Tableau and other ODBC apps:

http://www.progress.com/products/datadirect-connect/odbc-drivers/data-sources/mongodb

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB just announced a connector for Tableau: 
http://techcrunch.com/2015/06/02/new-mongodb-connector-creates-direct-connection-to-data-visualization-tools/ , but I could not find any details on their website.